# calculate $\mathbb{E}[X]$ . what is wrong in my attempt?

Tags: probability, expected-value

friend A choose 3 cards from 10 cards packet, then he return the cards to the pack. friend B choose 3 cards from the same pack in an independent way from friend A. Let $X$ be the number of cards that didnt choose by any of the friends, calculate $\mathbb{E}[X]$

First I can see that $4\leq X \leq 7$
$${p(X=4)}
~=~ \frac{\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}\binom{10}{3}}.$$
$${p(X=5)}
~=~ \frac{\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{2}\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}\binom{10}{3}}.$$
$${p(X=6)}
~=~ \frac{\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{1}\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}\binom{10}{3}}.$$
$${p(X=7)}
~=~ \frac{\binom{10}{3}\binom{3}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}\binom{10}{3}}.$$

but I dont get the right answer when I calculate it according to $$
\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_{t \in R_{X}} t \cdot \mathbb{P}(X=t)
$$

Comment: Can you explain your formula for $P(X=4)$ for example?

Comment: Yes, for a case that only 4 cards didnt choose by neither A or B we need that friends A will pick 3 cards from the 10 in the pack and also that friend B will pick another 3 cards from the 7 that have left, I divide that in my $\Omega$

Comment: You results seem correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $A_i= \{$ the card number $i$ was not chose by any friend $\}$. Then
$X = \sum_{i=1}^{10} I_{A_i}$, where $I$ is indicator function.
Hence $EX = \sum_i P(A_i) = 10 P(A_1)$.

Put $B = \{$ the card number $1$ was not chose by the first friend $\}$ and $C = \{$ the card number $1$ was not chose by the second friend $\}$. Then
$A_1=  B\cap C$, where $B$ and $C$ are independent and $P(B) = P(C) =0.7$.
Hence $P(A_1) = 0.49$ and the answer is $4.9$.

Comment: Nice approach but how did you got the number 0.7?

Comment: @Sagigever, event $B$ means that the first friend takes 3 cards from 10 and don't chose the first card. Hence $P(B) = \binom{9}{3} / \binom{10}{3} = \frac{7}{10}$.

Answer (score 2):

In addition do @BotnakovN. 's answer, the following Python session shows that the OP's original computation is correct

```
>>> from scipy.special import binom as b
>>> x = b(10, 3)
>>> 4 * b(7, 3)/x + 5 * b(7, 2) * 3/x + 6 * 7 *3/x + 7 * 1/x
4.9
```